# I am facing problem in this code of custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I am written this code for angularjs custom directive, but not geeting the output. Please help me.**strong text**

```
 <html>
   <head>
    <title>Directives</title>
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="angular-1.7.6\angular.js"></script>
     <script src="angular-1.7.6\angular.min.js"></script>
     <script>
       var app=angular.module("arrayApp", [])
       app.controller("arrayCtrl", function ($scope) {
       $scope.colors = ["RED","GREEN","BLUE","YELLOW" ];
       });
       app.directive('mycolor', function() {
       return {
       restrict: 'E',
       transclude: 'true',
       template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
       link: function(scope, element, attr){
       element.append("<strong>"+attr.title+"</strong>");
      }
    };
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="arrayApp">
<div ng-controller="arrayCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="c in colors">
        <my-c title="{{c}}">
            BASIC COLOR:
        </my-c>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Iam not getting where I am wrong.

Comment: Why are you including Angular 1.6.9 and then 1.7.6 twice, both min and uncompressed version?

Comment: ok adrian what next I should do

Comment: following adrian's suggestion, i am getting an output of 4 values without any console errors. is that right?

Comment: kenmistry can you share your code with me

Comment: @kenmistry are you getting array values or its just BASIC COLOR printing four times

Comment: @rai please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the output as
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMVA5.png)

The code is as below :

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Directives</title>
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
     <script>
       var app=angular.module("arrayApp", [])
       app.controller("arrayCtrl", function ($scope) {
       $scope.colors = ["RED","GREEN","BLUE","YELLOW" ];
       });
       app.directive('mycolor', function() {
       return {
       restrict: 'E',
       transclude: 'true',
       template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
       link: function(scope, element, attr){
       element.append("<strong>"+attr.title+"</strong>");
      }
    };
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="arrayApp">
<div ng-controller="arrayCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="c in colors">
        <mycolor title="{{c}}">
            BASIC COLOR:
        </mycolor>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Akansha It is what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes Ajinkya same output

Answer (score 1):

Firstly change the name of the directive into `camelCase`, it's a good convention for naming directives. So your directive name should be `myColor`.

Then use the directive like - `my-color`. Below is the whole code -

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Directives</title>
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
     <script>
       var app=angular.module("arrayApp", [])
       app.controller("arrayCtrl", function ($scope) {
       $scope.colors = ["RED","GREEN","BLUE","YELLOW" ];
       });
       app.directive('myColor', function() {
       return {
       restrict: 'E',
       transclude: 'true',
       template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
       link: function(scope, element, attr){
       element.append("<strong>"+attr.title+"</strong>");
      }
    };
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="arrayApp">
<div ng-controller="arrayCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="c in colors">
        <my-color title="{{c}}">
            BASIC COLOR:
        </my-color>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output - 
[image]

Comment: thanks @Arnab Roy I didn't noticed that,this small change has made my code to give the same output

Comment: @Akansha if this solves your problem then you should accept this answer.